# Why does the result depend on where the measure is defined?

Tags: dax

I am trying the following two queries

query 1:

```
DEFINE
MEASURE 'Product'[x] = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Product', 'Product'[Color]="Red"))
EVALUATE
    ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES('Product'[Brand]), "count",  [x])
```

and

query 2:

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES('Product'[Brand]), "count",  COUNTROWS(FILTER('Product', 'Product'[Color]="Red")))
```

in dax.do and the result is different. I cannot really understand why. Any ideas?

In particular the first query returns

[image: query 1 results]

whilst query 2 returns

[image: query 2 results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when you call any measure within another measure, a `CALCULATE` is wrapped around the (called) measure.

This causes context transition, which is the transformation of active row context into a filter context for the calculation.

Using this formula returns the same as your query 1:

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES('Product'[Brand]), "count",  CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS(FILTER('Product', 'Product'[Color]="Red"))))
```